# ocrfeeder doesn't detect anything

Tags: ocr, tesseract

When I try to detect text on my jpeg, it shows correctly all areas where it suspects text and images, but when I export it to ODT it only creates an ODT with empty text- and imageframes.

Do I have to configure `tesseract` somehow?

(I use Ubuntu 14.10 32bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Open the ocrfeeder program.

Edit the engine: Click `Tools` - `OCR Engine`

Select the `Tesseract engine` and click `Edit`

Where it says `arguments engine` changed the script for this:

```
$IMAGE $FILE -l eng -psm 3 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null; cat $FILE.txt; rm $FILE $FILE.txt
```

To export the document click `File` - `Export`

Select the desired output format.

If the document has pictures I advise using the `html` format text.

If only has text the best is to use the format plain text `txt` .

Comment: You just need to setup the engine command line on OCR Feeder settings.
replacing `$LANG` with `-l lang_id`
where `lang_id` is the id as shown on the correspondin language package.
The lang_ids can be found with `apt-get search tesseract-ocr` for example spa = spanish, fra = french, deu = german, nld = dutch; ita = italian, por = portugese, ... If you just want to scan in your language, you can stick with `$LANG` which is your system language

Comment: @rubo77 thanks for the hint! But i think you mean `apt-cache search`